# Someone Comment 1000 times in a Day in My WordPress Site, What Can i Do

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

My Website, How to Stop Spamming in [WordPress](https://www.findtricks.in/thop-tv-mod-apk/),  Plz Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Google recaptcha to your comment forms. You have two ways:

1) with plugins: https://beautifulthemes.com/blog/recaptcha-in-wordpress-comments/ 
2) without plugin: https://www.oueta.com/wordpress/add-google-recaptcha-to-wordpress-comments-without-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Use **Akismet Anti-Spam** plugin or **Jetpack plugin** in order to avoid spam and get protection to your website. I always use both of them and they are free.

You can also add Google ReCaptcha to comment form also.